What does "a receipt for the money" mean?
collinsdictionary.com:
(1) I wrote her a receipt for the money.
The preposition "for" confuses me.
What does "for" mean here?
What does "a receipt for the money" mean?

She gave the subject some money and they, in exchange for the money, gave her a receipt to be kept as a proof of giving such money.

@kos Where can this action occur: at home, in a store, in an office, in the government? And between whom? Thanks.

I think you're overthinking this, or possibly you haven't looked up what a receipt is; I don't know where you live, but I'm sure you'll have receipts there, too, they're given in exchange for money all the time, when buying stuff at a grocery store, when paying for a haircut at a salon etc, and sometimes they're used (at least where I live) to "certify" (for lack of a better word) that one individual has received money from another individual, without the need for giving something in exchange. Does this clear things up?

@kos Where I live, salesmen of grocery stores don't write a receipt, they just give it in printed form. The only example I can imagine where (1) can occur is in the service sector when there is a prepayment. For example: a technician takes a prepayment for his services when he comes right a customer's home: a customer gives him money and a technician writes a paper that he got this money to do a repair of the customer's equipment. But you say, where you live, writing a receipt happens at a grocery store and at a haircut salon. This all looks very strange to me.

The "printed form" is also called a receipt; I think that's where the confusion is arising from. I said "they're given in exchange for money all the time [...]", but I never said in written form (I was actually implying the printed form); but I was (implicitly) referring to the written form when talking about ""certifying" (for lack of a better word) that one individual has received money from another individual", or, as you brought up, when paying professionals carrying out some work in your house, that also happens here all the time.

Just to be clear: this is a receipt, and this also is a receipt

I would've called it a receipt if it didn't contain a pledge within the text. I don't think it's called a receipt anymore at that point. You should ask a native speaker though, I may be wrong. Perhaps you can ask gotube under their answer. To my understanding, much like in my native language, a receipt only involves "certifying" having received something from someone else; the included pledge to me makes it look more like a written agreement of some sort.

In the UK, if someone does some work on my house and then I pay them for doing that work, I expect to get a receipt from them stating that I have paid them. Without that receipt I have no proof that they have been paid. This is specially so if I pay them cash; it is less important if the payment is via a bank and so can be seen on bank statements. Without a receipt, an unscrupulous worker might say I have not paid and demand more money.

In the context of a receipt, the preposition "for" indicates what the receipt acknowledges the receipt of.
If someone gives you $10 and you give them either a machine-printed slip of paper or a written note which indicates that you have received $10 from them, that slip or note is a receipt for $10.
So, "I wrote her a receipt for the money" means I wrote her a note that said that I had received the money from her.

Could you tell me please if John Brown writes the following paper, can we consider it as an example of receipt?: "I, John Brown (passport №457464), took the chainsaw (model "red devil 4854s") in an excellent condition from Bill Black (passport №6785867) today (the 4th of May, 2024) and pledge to give it back to him tomorrow (the 5th of May, 2024) in the same condition." And John's signature at the end.

@Loviii That would be considered a receipt without the part about pledging to return it. However, using the term "receipt" for something other than money is so uncommon that, depending on your context, I'd consider using a distinct term, like "note of receipt" to distinguish it from the normal use of "receipt".

@Loviii - In my country, that document agreeing to return the chainsaw would be a loan agreement.

@MichaelHarvey: no mention of payment, not a loan. Just a promise to return it.  Friendly, but untrusting, neighbor.

@jmoreno - in the UK I have a strong feeling that such a document would have no legal force.

@MichaelHarvey: probably not to the extent that there could be damages for being a bit late, but it would serve to establish that they had the chainsaw, and its condition at 5he time. I would expect that if someone had such a receipt created, that the expected sequence would be sign/take chainsaw, counter sign/return chainsaw and that the receipt would actually end up in the hands of the borrower with a signature saying it was returned in good condition.

OP: If you do a web search for receipt book (particularly an image search) you'll find such machine printed forms  as mentioned here for writing out receipts by hand. Such books can generally be bought at a local newsagency or office supply shop, in several styles. But as the answer indicates, you can literally just write on a piece of paper something more or less like "Received  from  on  for ", sign that, and it's a formal record of the receipt of money. I've done so a handful of times in my life, perhaps ten times or so.

@Glen_b As far as I understand, the pages of a receipt book must have a special edge which they attach to the book with (e.g. an edge with the row of round holes), because the pages must be easy to tear out in order to be given to a customer. But also I came across receipt books with the ordinary pages which are not meant for tearing out (e.g. this book). How can this be explained? Thanks.

@Loviii Why don't you think those pages tear out? It looks like yellow carbon copy paper below each white sheet, so it should be designed to tear out.

@Loviii - that second book does indeed have pages meant for tearing out. It is a standard NCR (no carbon required) receipt book. The top copy is given to the customer; there will be one or more coloured copies left in the book. https://mintsigns.co.uk/service/branded-stationery/ncr-pads/

Please note: I am only responding in this manner because I do not have the reputation to comment. I 100% agree with @gotube's answer.
As to a general "rule" for those looking to improve their skill in English, the word for represents an exchange, e.g., money for services rendered; or an addition to something, e.g., new cleats for the football team.
Of course, there are exceptions to every rule, especially in English. Don't get me started on phonetics. 

This isn't a rule at all, it's just one of the many ways for can be used. Others are to indicate a purpose ("a bucket for carrying water"), to indicate continuous action over time ("travelling for a few weeks"), or to indicate other relationships ("a taste for fine wine"). Dictionary.com gives 32 such distinct usages, although other dictionaries may distinguish them differently.

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
